# How to restore the default effect of listview row item after changing its(row item's) selector(background of selected item etc.)?

Tags: android

I am implementing multiple selection on a listview with custom ActionMode(not listview's default ActionMode that comes with AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener()). It is just changing the background color of each row item and within the Adapter class there is a SparseBooleanArray to keep track of highlighted row items(note that i am not calling setselected() or any method, I am just highlighting the selected nodes and keeping the positions of highlighted rows inside the SparseBooleanArray). Now, what I want is to change back to the default mode(ripple or whatever there is in previous Android versions) after i deselect a row item.

Another thing, I am not setting any background color to the list rows before the multi selection,the adapter just puts it in the listvew in default style.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You will have to call the notifyDataSetChanged(), but before this, in the onBindViewHolder you will have to have a check

```
onBindViewHolder(..params, positions){
if(isPositionSetInYourSparseBooleanArray){
//Your background for set ones
}else{
//Your background for unset ones
}
}
```

To unset all, clear the sparse boolean array, since none of them will be set, all will fall to else and apply your background for unset ones. Dont forget to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after you unset your sparseArray

Comment: Is there any xml attribute to reset the effect?

Comment: Not know n to me